# Checking for available times with only 1 table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a single table and it has a list of reservations. Each reservations has a `ID` (primary key) a `roomNumber`, a `startTime` and an `endTime`.

I'm trying to find which rooms are available in a certain time frame. So if I wanted to see if there were any rooms free between 5-7 I'd search the table and find any rooms that don't have reservations at that time.

At first I thought I could do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT roomNumber
FROM  `reservations` A
WHERE NOT 
EXISTS (

SELECT NULL 
FROM  `reservations` B
WHERE A.roomNumber = B.roomNumber
AND (
B.starttime >  '5:00:00'
AND B.starttime <  '7:00:00'
)
OR (
B.endtime >  '5:00:00'
AND B.endtime <  '7:00:00'
)
)
```

But I quickly realized why this didn't work. Since all the reservations are in the same table it will return the room number if it ever find a row where the times do not conflict. Meaning if room 4 had a reservation at 5-7 and another one at 3-4 my query would still return room 4 because the 3-4 row does technically evaluate to True based on my condition.

I can't modify the table and I'm not sure what to do because I've never encountered something like this.

Comment: What is `court`? Give some sample data for understanding.

Comment: Event A can be said to overlap Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends, and ends after Event B starts. You can draw a simple diagram to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your conditions to these.

```
SELECT DISTINCT roomNumber
FROM  `reservations` A
WHERE NOT 
EXISTS (

SELECT NULL 
FROM  `reservations` B
WHERE A.court = B.court
AND (
B.starttime <  '7:00:00'
AND B.endtime >  '5:00:00'
)
)
```

Comment: Tested it and it seemed to work but if I set the starttime and endtime to the exact same as an existing reservation it will still return that room.

Comment: Oh, come on. Don't say you don't know how to fix that!

Comment: Change the > to >= and < to <=. :)

Comment: Sorry, it was one of those bugs that it was so easy that it became hard.

Comment: Haha, I think I can understand. xP

Comment: Note that in general an uncorellated subquery will outperform a correlated one, but this is an elegant solution nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks. You're a pal :)

Answer (score 0):

Simplified query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT roomNumber FROM reservations 
WHERE 
    (startTime NOT BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '07:00:00')
AND (endTime   NOT BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '07:00:00')
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/RGD69170)

Comment: I never even knew that `NOT BETWEEN` was a thing. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

I think this would work:

```
WITH ALL_ROOMS as (SELECT DISTINCT roomNumber
FROM  `reservations`),

BOOKED_ROOMS as (
SELECT DISTINCT A.roomNumber
FROM ALL_ROOMS A
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT roomNumber, starttime
FROM 'reservations') B
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT roomNumber, endtime
FROM 'reservations') C
)
WHERE (B.starttime > '5:00:00' AND B.starttime <  '7:00:00')
OR (B.endtime > '5:00:00' AND B.endtime <  '7:00:00')
)

SELECT A.roomNumber
from ALL_ROOMS A
LEFT JOIN BOOKED_ROOMS B
ON A.roomNumber = B.roomNumber
WHERE B.roomNumber is NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT roomnumber 
FROM   `reservations` A 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL 
                   FROM   `reservations` B 
                   WHERE  A.roomnumber = B.roomnumber 
                          AND ( B.starttime NOT BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '07:00:00') 
                          AND ( B.endtime NOT BETWEEN '05:00:00' AND '07:00:00') )
```